# Tracing a bounce in postfix logs

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to send a notification email from Asterisk through Postfix to let users know they have voicemail messages, but the following is showing up in the postfix logs:

```
Feb 15 15:21:02 myserver postfix/local[12751]: BF8E9A18887: to=<alfred@somewhere3.com>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "alfred")
```

I am using my ISP's SMTP servers as a relay, and I have tested and been able to send messages to the user through their SMTP servers using telnet.

What else can I check to see where this bounce is coming from? It seems to be postfix, but I don't know what to do next.

**main.cf**

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = somewhere3.com

inet_interfaces = localhost
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
relayhost = [smtp.myisp.net]
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES

#smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/saslpasswd
#broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
#smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
#smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
#smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postfix logs you posted indicates that your mail server is not relaying your message to the relayhost for the simple reason that the domain of the recipient matches to the `mydestination` parameter. If the domain is part of the `mydestination`, then the message is delivered through the local program, it is not relayed, as you can see in `relay=local` from the logs. If you want every email sent to be relayed, then leave the mydestination field empty.